# AWS Amplify signedIn Variable is undefined

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am using the aws-amplify from this [site](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular)  I noticed on this site, `this.signedIn` is not used anywhere on this link. I am attempting to use is as an indicator true/false value as to if the user is signed in.

This is the code:

```
  constructor(public mediaObserver: MediaObserver, private amplifyService: AmplifyService ){
this.amplifyService.authStateChange$
.subscribe(authState => {
    this.signedIn = authState.state === 'signedIn';
  });
  console.log('This is from home constructor for signedIn boolean value ', this.signedIn)
```

`this.signedIn is sent to the console window as : undefined`

Comment: It's asynchronous code. You should log it in the subscription function.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanHussien you are correct.  When I log it in the subscribe function it is not displayed since nothing changed. I am using to determine if the user is logged in. According to local storage I am logged in. Everytime I refresh the page, signedIn becomes undefined. When I log in initially signed in is true. Bue refresh, it becomes undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppComponent` does not set an initial value for `signedIn` so by default it will be `undefined`:

```
export class AppComponent {
    signedIn: boolean;
    ...
}
```

Your `console.log(...)` is within the components constructor and so when the log call is hit - the value is still `undefined`.

You will still be able to refer to `signedIn` from  within your template as the `undefined` value will resolve to `false`. Or you can be more explicit and initialize with `signedIn: boolean = false`.

Comment: I am logged into the app. When I refresh the page why does signedIn not become true since I am logged in? I moved the console log to ngOnInit() and signedIn is still undefined. The subscribe must be waiting for something. What else should I do?

Comment: It sounds like `authStateChange$` is not emitting a value on page refresh. If you move your console log into the `subscribe(...)` callback and nothing appears in the log then you'll know for sure. Alternatively set a break point on this line: `this.signedIn = authState.state === 'signedIn';`. If it does hit - it means nothing is emitted.